# How to attach files to dotnet zip library c#

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am using dotnet zip library to create zip file. My files are saved into a database and I am reading each row and load file data into memory from the database and save the memory stream to zip file. my below code works fine.

```
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zip;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BBATRIDIP\SQLSERVER2008R2;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                string query = String.Format(@"SELECT Name, ContentType, Data FROM [TestTable]");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = null;
                ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
                zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB each segment size would be
                // the above line would split zip file into multiple files and each file
                //size would be 1MB
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        byte[] data = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                        memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
                        string strFile = reader["Name"].ToString() + "\\" + reader["ContentType"].ToString();
                        ZipEntry ze = zip.AddEntry(strFile, memStream);
                        int xx = 0;
                    }
                }
                zip.Save(@"e:\MyCustomZip.zip");

                memStream.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("Job Done");
                // here u can save the zip in memory stream also there is a overload insteaa of saving in HD
            }
        }
```

but if i change a bit into the code then corrupted zip file is creating. if i change this line `zip.Save(@"e:\MyCustomZip.zip");` then problem occur.

```
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BBATRIDIP\SQLSERVER2008R2;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string query = String.Format(@"SELECT Name, ContentType, Data FROM [TestTable]");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = null;
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
        zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB each segment size would be
        // the above line would split zip file into multiple files and each file
        //size would be 1MB
        zip.Save(@"e:\MyCustomZip.zip");
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                byte[] data = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
                string strFile = reader["Name"].ToString() + "\\" + reader["ContentType"].ToString();
                ZipEntry ze = zip.AddEntry(strFile, memStream);
                int xx = 0;
            }
        }


        memStream.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("Job Done");
        // here u can save the zip in memory stream also there is a overload insteaa of saving in HD
    }
```

I want to create zip with zero kb initially and when I will add stream to zip in loop then zip file size will increase gradually. if you see my above code where I try to do that but I got no success. what am I doing wrong in the code?

### Another issue

dotnet zip compression ratio not good. i zip a 152 KB doc file with dotnet zip and when zip was created then i was zip file size was 136KB. is there any tweak exist which create small size zip file. share the knowledge. thanks

Comment: It's wrong to save a file and then add stuff to it. It's the other way around. It is strange that the library would even allow this. Probably a bug.

Comment: If the library allowed it your code work, wouldn't it?

Comment: library allow but when run then a corrupted zip is creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking at the [documentation for `ZipFile.Save`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/22db64c9-849a-9069-4d15-2da91c318f02.htm), we see the following:

> Use this when creating a new zip file, or when updating a zip archive.

So, it seems that you need to call this repeatedly to get the "update" behaviour you are looking for. As such just need to move your `Save` into the loop:

```
//...
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 1024 * 1024; 

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        byte[] data = (byte[])reader["Data"];
        memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
        string strFile = 
            reader["Name"].ToString() + "\\" + reader["ContentType"].ToString();
        ZipEntry ze = zip.AddEntry(strFile, memStream);
        zip.Save(@"e:\MyCustomZip.zip");
    }
}
```

With regards to your second question (never a good idea on SO, try to stick to one problem per question):

Without knowing what you are compressing, it's very difficult to speculate about what kind of compression ratio you might achieve. If the data is already compressed (e.g. compressed image/video such as jpeg/h264), zipping isn't going to give you any gains whatsoever. Your only hint about the nature of the content is that it is a "doc". If you're talking about a modern Word document (docx), this is already a zip compressed folder structure. Gains will be minimal. If it's another kind of doc, perhaps it contains embedded (compressed) media? This will also be relatively incompressible.

Comment: i was trying to zip a doc file whose size was 152 KB and after creating zip file i was size become 136KB. not very good i guess. is there any option to tweak anything in code to get better compression. let me know. thanks

Comment: @Mou: What is a "doc"? A word document? Docx?

Comment: The Save call is supposed to be made when all data has been added. Calling it in a loop might even exhibit quadratic time behavior.

Comment: @usr Yes, I was considering this might be the case too. I suppose it's down to OP to test whether it gives acceptable performance. I'm struggling to understand the use-case for such code...